# Mariadb error after update

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Around one week ago arrive a new update (10.1.30) after the update our system is recursively dying.

- MariaDB dying and restarting at random time.
- Some stored procedure calling get "Lost connection during query" error and restarting MariaDB. When debugging procedure then other unity dying the system.
- Yesterday lost a table (.frm file going) this table is a Opencart product_description. But this table have only select query.
- Error log only one InnoDB table marked as crashed. But this table i truncate... delete - recreate ... give to reaper... (:

We try to use MariaDB 10.2.xx but the problem not solved.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Just for the record...did you stopped the service before running the update?...I always backup up the entire database before doing something like that, that way you can purge your current installation and install a fresh one(without updating)

Comment: Yes, was stopped it. After for try we do it a purge reinstall.